# How to access $q library with webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have a project, that i'm packing with webpack.
However I have this one issue, where I can't access the angular promise library.

I have a properties.js file, with the following code:

```
define(['qlik', 'ng!$q'], function(qlik, $q) {
  var defer = $q.defer();  
  ...
  ...  
})
```

and when I try to hit 'npm run build' in cmd line, I get this output:

```
ERROR in ./properties.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '$q' in '...path...\src'
 @ ./properties.js 1:0-545:2
```

Anyone who knows the answer to this?

Thanks in advance.

//Rasmus